# displaying jsHint and cssLint results in sonar

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, checkstyle, jshint, csslint

jsHint and cssLint can output their results in to standard xml (sjlint.xml and csslint.xml format) file.

Is there a way to display those results with sonar?

What I'm trying to do is to run a jenkins job that will run validations on java script and show the results in Sonar.

Thank you.

Comment: Sound this help: https://github.com/boxuk/jslint-jenkins-plugin

Comment: thanks, but this will run jsLint and display the resuls in jenkis while I wish to run jsHint and display the results on sonar

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to develop a new Sonar Plugin. Take a look at the following links that might help you.

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Developing+Plugins
- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+hosting

Digging around, I found this closed Sonar issue suggesting that Sonar's [Javascript plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JavaScript+Plugin) works better, compared to jsLint:

- [SONARPLUGINS-1829](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1829)